# Aditive functor characterization. Aditive iff right/left exact.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, functors

I need to prove this:

*Let F be a functor between abelian categories. F is aditive iff is right exact or left exact.*

I think that for <-- I'll need to use the characterization:

*F between aditive categories is an aditive functor iff F preserves products (or coproducts).*

So I'll need to prove that if F is right exact, then it preserves coproducts
and if F is left exact, it preserves products, and then I could use this result, but I'm not sure about it.

Any help or idea to both sides of the proof is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many examples of additive functors which are neither left exact nor right exact.

Comment: Functors like that between abelian categories? Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: (Not precisely a duplicate, but the question is answered there, and this question has been already essentially answered in the comments and appears to be abandoned so it seems harmless to mark it as a duplicate.)